# Page skips when the content updates (from a longer content to a shorter content)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

everyone, I'm a graphic designer and I am building my personal website. I get stuck on the problem with window scrollTop when I load a content shorter than the default content.

Well, here are some details :

The page is a simple one-column-page, the visitors will scroll the page down to view the projects. Each project contains a title whose css position is `position: sticky`and is displayed with images by default. In the title, there is a button called 'text'.

When the button clicked, the content of container `<contentProjet>`will toggled between image and text. That is to say the images of project displayed by default will be replaced with text of project and vice versa.
So far so good.

But if you aren't at the top of project, say you have scrolled for a while ($(.contentProject).scrollTop!=0), the moment you click the stiky button to show the text, there comes the problem: 
when the content of `<contentProjet>` changes from image to text (whose length is shorter), well the page displayed in the clientHeight section skips. Here is the code to demonstrate problem. Thank you for your advice and help!

```js
function AjaxSwitchProjet(){
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this)
    el.text() == el.data('text-note')
    ? (
      el.text(el.data('text-image')),
      target = el.data('target-note'),
       el.parent().next().find('.d-none').fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'block'),
       el.parent().next().find('.carousel').fadeOut(1000)
      )
    : (
      el.text(el.data('text-note')),
      target = el.data('target-image'),
       el.parent().next().find('.d-none').fadeOut(1000),
       el.parent().next().find('.carousel').fadeIn(1000)
    )
  // el.parent().next().hide().load(target + '.php', function(){
  // }).fadeIn(1000);
   
    
   return false;
});
}
AjaxSwitchProjet();


// add position sticky to titles
```

```css
.text {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  line-height:2px;
  padding:2px;
}

h3 {
font-size:24px;
}

#first{
background-color : red;
}

#seconde{
background-color:blue
}

.d-none{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <article>
              <div id="firstProject">
                  <div class="text" id='first'>
                     <h3 data-projet="firstProject">
                         title of firstProject
                     </h3>
                     <div class="button" 
                       data-text-image="image"
                       data-text-note="text" 
                       data-target-note="noteFirstProject"
                       data-target-image='imgFirstProject'>
                         text
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="contentProject">
                    <div class="carousel">
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                      </div>           
                      <div class='d-none'>
                        <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet bresaola burgdoggen kielbasa pancetta chuck hamburger cupim shank meatloaf sirloin biltong leberkas jerky shankle. Prosciutto drumstick bresaola, pork ham capicola cow swine landjaeger sirloin cupim tenderloin tail pork chop chuck. 
                        </p>         
                      </div>
                     </div>
              </div>
    </article>


         <article>
              <div id="secondeProject">
                  <div class="text" id='seconde'>
                     <h3 data-projet="secondeProject">
                         title of secondeProject
                     </h3>
                     <div class="button" 
                       data-text-image="image"
                       data-text-note="text" 
                       data-target-note="noteSecondeProject"
                       data-target-image='imgSecondeProject'>
                          text
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentProject">
                
                                      <div class="carousel">
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                           <figure><img src="http://placehold.jp/369x639.png"></figure>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class='d-none'>
                        <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet bresaola burgdoggen kielbasa pancetta chuck hamburger cupim shank meatloaf sirloin biltong leberkas jerky shankle. Prosciutto drumstick bresaola, pork ham capicola cow swine landjaeger sirloin cupim tenderloin tail pork chop chuck. 
                        </p>         
                      </div>
                </div>
             </div>
    </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are replacing the content, the document length (in pixels) changes and the viewport will adapt to the change. That you cannot change.
If you instead place the text as an overlay the height will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help, You mean that i can place the text as a overlay to the image? could you give me more hints ?

Comment: if so, i'am afraid that is not the solution im looking for.

Comment: Sorry, yes, place the text in a container either absolutely over the images with opacity, or beside the images. Could be sticky as the header.

Comment: You could possibly freeze the element height before replacing images with text. But that will leave you with a lot of space below the text.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yeah, freeze the height idea occurs to me, too, but i consider that it would be less friendly for user's experience Otherwise, i tried doing some math with the scroll position,  no luck